# Execute While in SQl Script in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i want to execute the SQL Script below, therefore i used ibatis Script Runner

```
Connection "con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Database")" 

ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(con, true, false);
// Give the input file to Reader
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aSQLScriptFilePath));
// Execute script
sr.runScript(reader);
```

But there is the Problem, that While loops will not  be completely executed.
I pointed out that the problem comes because the Script Runner didn´t wait until he while loop is completely done. So there are only 386 and not 1000 rows created.
I got the same Problem using the Java Statement execute method(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

```
 stmnt.execute("DECLARE @variable int = 1 WHILE (@variable<=1000) BEGIN INSERT INTO BatchTest2 SELECT @variable SET @variable=@variable+1 END" );
```

But if i set

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

behind stmnt.execute the while loop is completeley done and i get 1000 rows like i wanted.
So my question is, if it is possible to execute the complete While loop whitout using Thread.sleep.?

Thank you in advance!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE test;

CREATE TABLE test(
spalte1 int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

DECLARE @variable int = 1
WHILE (@variable<=1000)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test
SELECT @variable
SET @variable=@variable+1
END
```

Comment: Have you tried using transactions?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html Or batches:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378070.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to below example from [MKYONG](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-run-a-mysql-script-using-java/) for same. Hope this helps you out.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner;

/**
 * 
 @author Dhinakaran Pragasam
 */
public class RunSqlScript {
    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {

        String aSQLScriptFilePath = "path/to/sql/script.sql";

        // Create MySql Connection
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "username", "password");
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            // Initialize object for ScripRunner
            ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(con, false, false);

            // Give the input file to Reader
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                               new FileReader(aSQLScriptFilePath));

            // Exctute script
            sr.runScript(reader);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to Execute" + aSQLScriptFilePath
                    + " The error is " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works fine up o the point where i want to execute the while loop, like i said i only get ~300 rows but the while loop should create 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Without having `ScriptRunner` at hand, a possible solution might be to use a procedure and then calling the procedure in the script.

```
Create Procedure insertData()
As
Begin
  DECLARE @variable int = 1
  WHILE (@variable<=1000)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test
    SELECT @variable
    SET @variable=@variable+1
  END
End

IF OBJECT_ID('test') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE test;

CREATE TABLE test(
  spalte1 int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
EXEC insertData;
```